# How to implement an enum in multiple files?

Tags: c++, enums

I have three files, the main, the Satellite1.h (or header) and Satellite1.cpp

I'm having trouble implementing this, the compiler states that `first` doesn't name a type, how do I implement the enum? I saw some code where the enum name
was placed to the left of Satellite1 but when I tried recreating it an error showed up where it says `first`(one of origins elements) doesn't name a type

in Satellite1.H

```
class Satellite1{};

enum class origin
{
first;
second
}
```

(in Satellite1.cpp)

```
#include "Satellite1.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

origin Satellite::soof()
{
}

 //main.cpp is pretty much empty so I didn't include
```

Comment: You can read more on the syntax for enum declaration here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error.

```
enum class origin
{
     first,
     second
};
```